# Why isn't the molecule of water linear straight?

Tags: water, physical-chemistry, orbitals, molecules, chemical-compounds

When you see models of water you see something like this:
[image: Image of oxygen atom bonded with hydrogen atoms on a side. The whole thing is shapd like a micky mouse face.]

The hydrogens in the water molecule become negatively charged because the oxygen pulls electrons more. So why don't they repel and move to the opposite sides of the oxygen? Or just form on opposite sides in the first place?

Comment: This is more of a chmistry question anyway the oxygen is sp3 hybridized there a two lone pairs forming a tetrahedral structure with hydrogen and lone pair lone pair repulsion is much stronger than hydrogen hydrogen repulsion.

Comment: @SohamPatil, why not post this as an answer? -NN

Comment: Beside the fact that this doesn't not affect your reasoning, the hydrogen atoms have a positive charge.

Comment: Walsh diagrams can be helpful to explain this from a molecular orbital perspective. For a very verbose answer to this and related questions, read this answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/57973/11568.

Comment: Not trying to argue, but I am *very* surprised to see that this question was so extremely well received. I'm pretty sure if I posted such a question on Chemistry.SE, it would get heavily downvoted and closed - the reason being simple: the shape of water molecule is a universal example when VSEPR theory is taught (and if OP has not yet reached the level when VSEPR is taught, it's too early to ask about molecular shapes then). Plus, a simple Google Search yields many satisfactory results.

Comment: @TRC Even a schoolchild has a right to ask why the molecule isn't straight. The answer can be that it is very complicated (details follow...). That is not a reason to ridicule the schoolchild for asking such question.

Comment: @VladimirF - My experience so far at Chemistry.SE (and my passive observation at Physics and Maths.SE) suggests exactly the opposite. At the very least, the schoolchild, when posting here, should atleast have searched Google (and better, textbooks) prior to asking here. Then the question of "What exactly didn't you understand in the Google explanations?" follows. Based on what exactly the OP didn't understand, the answer can be framed in a more focussed way. Again, there's no harm in being curious, but a schoolchild's naive, unresearched questions do not fit SE standards AFAIK.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are six electrons in the outer orbital of an oxygen atom. In a water molecule two of these electrons bond with the lone electron of each hydrogen atom to form two “bond pairs”. The remaining four oxygen electrons pair up to form two “lone pairs” (because of quantum mechanics, it is energetically favourable for electrons with opposite spins to form pairs).

If the repulsive forces between the bond pairs and the lone pairs were completely symmetrical then the four pairs would form the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, and the angle between the hydrogen atoms (the “bond angle”) would be approximately 109 degrees (the exact angle is $\cos^{-1}\left(-\tfrac 1 3 \right)$). This is what happens when four hydrogen atoms and one carbon atom form a molecule of methane, which has four bond pairs.

However, in water the repulsive forces are not quite symmetrical and the hydrogen atoms are pushed a bit closer together - the actual bond angle is about 104 degrees.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#Structure) for more details.

Comment: In particular, the lone pairs are closer to the oxygen nucleus (because they don't have hydrogen nuclei tugging them away), so they need to be further apart in angular terms, so the actual covalent bonds are pushed together. The same effect happens in ammonia, with the bond angle around $107^\circ$. The effect is about $2.5^\circ$ per lone pair.

Comment: @PM2Ring In the absence of lone pairs (as in e.g. methane), yes.

Comment: The image in this answer is a useful illustration:
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41189/estimation-of-the-bond-angle-of-water/41198#41198

Comment: This answer has it backwards. It implies an ideal bond angle for water be a tetrahedral angle. This is false. The ideal angle would be 90° as my answer highlights. This can be seen when comparing heavier homologues. Furthermore, one lone pair is predicted by calculation to be almost perfectly p-shaped which is fundametally at odds with the 'ideally tetrahedron' hypothesis. The effect is similar in ammonia but increased steric strain from the third hydrogen atom increases the bond angles further. (Yes, I know the old backwards argument is still present in many textbooks.)

Comment: Another interesting question synapse: then why HS2 is linear, it should be similar to water on the same reasoning.

Comment: @peterh: What's "HS2"? Neither [hydrogen sulfide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide) ($\rm H_2S$) nor [hydrogen disulfide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_disulfide) ($\rm H_2S_2$) are linear molecules.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry I wanted to write H2S, it was a typo.

Comment: @peterh That doesn't help though. H2S has a bond angle of 92° as stated in my answer so it is most definitely *not* linear.

Answer (score 22):

Let's start by taking a look at the 'bare' oxygen atom. While simplistic depictions of atoms often show the electrons orbiting the nucleus on various circular orbits as if they were planets, quantum mechanics predicts something somewhat different. Instead of imagining electrons as tiny planets on fixed orbits, it is better to think of them as standing waves. These waves have energies which can be calculated and the predicted result is that:

- the lowest energy standing wave is essentially a sphere
- the second-lowest energy standing wave is a larger sphere but with a spherical node inside
- the third-lowest energy standing wave**s** are a set of three which look a little bit like dumbbells. These all have a planar node passing through the nucleus and the two parts on opposite sides of the nodal plane have different phases.

If you have dabbled a bit in chemistry, you may recognise these shapes as s and p orbitals.

In another result that directly derives from *ab initio* quantum mechanical calculations, the electrons have a weird property called *spin.* We don't need to understand what exactly *spin* is but the consequence of this property is that one single standing wave will always be 'occupied' by two electrons. If we now fill in oxygen's eight electrons into these waves, we can put two in the lowest energy wave (a 1s orbital), two in the second-lowest (a 2s) and the remaining four in the third-highest waves (the three 2p orbitals; one of these will be twice populated, the other two only contain a single electron).

Now to add hydrogen atoms. Hydrogen only has one of these orbitals occupied by its single electron: the 1s orbital. But how do we describe the bond that is being formed here? Well, quantum chemistry has answers to that too. As two atoms move closer, their standing waves overlap; and as waves do they can either overlap in constructive interference or destructive interference. For mathematical reasons, if we are putting two waves (orbitals) together like this, we need to have a result that also contains two waves (orbitals), which is why there will always be a bonding (constructive interference) and an antibonding orbital (destructive interference; a nodal plain vertically between the atoms, perpendicular to the bond axis).

If we first take a look at only a single hydrogen atom, this could approach the oxygen atom and thus by extension one of the p orbitals in different ways as shown in the image below. (Due to symmetry, only an angle between 0° and 90° makes sense; phase designation is arbitrary.)

[image: An s orbital approaching a p orbital at different angles]

At 0°, the possible overlap between the two orbitals and thus the extent of constructive/destructive interference is greatest. That means, if we add the two orbitals together as outlined above, the resulting orbital will have the lowest possible total energy and it will be most favourable to the system. At 45°, the overlap is less good, but still okay. At 90° we have a problem: whatever we may gain from constructive overlap on one side of the p orbital's nodal plane (the top half in the picture) we will lose from destructive overlap on the other side. These two sides mathematically cancel each other out so that overall there is zero energy gained by this type of bonding.

Having said that, I should return to the p orbitals themselves. As you may already know or have guessed, these can be thought of as 'pointing' in three different directions with 90° angles between them; much like the axes of a three-dimensional coordinate system. Therefore, if a hydrogen orbital maxes out the energy gain with one of these p orbitals, it will necessarily have zero overlap with the other two.

Nevertheless, this arrangement of the hydrogen atoms forming a 90° angle, each perfectly overlapping with exactly one of the half-occupied p orbitals is energetically the initially most favourable state. In the absence of other forces, this is what we should expect. Quite unlike what gandalf has suggested, tetrahedral arrangement is **not** favourable *a priori*, as it would require raising the energy of the two electrons in the s orbital in a process called *hybridisation*. The energy gained from lowering the energy levels of the p orbitals when forming $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybrid orbitals is **necessarily** less than the energy lost when raising the s electrons to that same energy level. This is why larger central atoms like sulphur (92° bond angle in $\mathrm{H_2S}$), selenium (91° in $\mathrm{H_2Se}$) and tellurium (90° in $\mathrm{H_2Te}$) have bond angles very close to 90°.

It should, at this point, be obvious why linear is not an option: it would require both hydrogen orbitals to interact with the same p orbital on oxygen. This isn't impossible *per se* (cf. compounds such as $\mathrm{XeF2}$); however, it is energetically very unfavourable in the case of two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom.

Nonetheless, we still have to explain why the angle is actually 104.5° – a pretty large deviation from the expected 90°. In a nutshell, this is because oxygen is very small and the bonds between oxygen and hydrogen are short. Thus, assuming a 90° bond angle the hydrogen atoms would be very close together and their nuclei repulse each other. This repulsion is slightly stronger (and thus, loses more energy) than the gain by a perfect bond angle. Therefore, the oxygen atom undergoes partial hybridisation to increase the bond angle. In this process, the two p orbitals which would form the bond each receive a contribution of the s orbital. Ultimately, instead of two dumbbells and a sphere the three orbitals will end up looking like two deformed dumbbells and a deformed sphere. (The third p orbital will remain unaffected as it is perpendicular to the two O–H bonds.) The sweet spot where the energy gain from reduced repulsion can no longer overcome the energy lost from introducing hybridisation is at approximately 104.5°, corresponding to the experimentally determined bond angle of water.

Finally note that the angle is not rigid. Slight deviations in the bond angle only cause a small increase in overall energy. In fact, all water molecules at more than a couple of kelvin above absolute zero are vibrating to some extent; one of the vibration modes involves increasing and decreasing the angle. So the 104.5° is, in actual fact, only the average and energetically most favourable outcome.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this very extensive explanation.